# Single Ubuntu on Ubuntu virtualization for ssh-rescue-access and disk-decryption

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualization, disk-encryption

I want to use dm-crypt on one of my Ubuntu servers, but I don't want to go there and type in the password every time I want to reboot.

What are my best options?

- Virtualize the whole system so I can SSH into the host and start the dm-crypt device somehow?
- Only encrypt data-partitions like `/home`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a system like that for a server a while ago. The key is to provide a minimal shell that allows you to unlock your system drive via SSH.

Back when I set it up, I followed a very complex guide which I wasn't able to dig up again. Instead, I found this (much shorter) version: [Remote unlocking LUKS encrypted LVM using Dropbear SSH in Ubuntu](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/2011/09/13/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu/)

The principal should be the same.

Comment: Is there something i have to keep in mind when doing kernel-upgrades or such? How does it work with RAID/LVM?

Comment: I only use that mechanism to unlock my system drive. The actual storage (which uses `md` for RAID) is unlocked separately. So I can't really say how this would all work with a single unlock at boot time.